# "Faster than" using with Future Simple

Tags: grammar, adjectives, future, comparatives, compound-adjectives

I'm just wondering if it is right to say that

- I'll learn English faster than they will translate this book

=or

- I'll learn English earlier than they will translate this book

I'm confused about using " faster than" and both parts of sentences are Future simple.. Is it okay? Maybe i should use other tenses .

Comment: I'd use *sooner than*; *faster* is usually used for how long it takes to do something, not for who finishes first. (Although if you start at the same time, these are equivalent measures, and we might use faster in cases like that. But here, it sounds like they might not have even started translating the book yet).

Comment: *I'll learn English **before** they finish this book* seems more natural than either of the example sentences.